# SQL login technique for authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a very basic question and want to know how other experts do this
I have an application with some 100s of users. I have been using SQL LOGINS to authenticate these users. These users have password policy enforced. and I face difficulty when any user's password is expired i.e. i have to reset it from SSMS myself. It sometimes becomes a difficult job along with other tasks that i do.

I was told by some experts that it is a good practice to create my own user table and have all the user details in that table. I have created a user table with following columns.

- User Id
- User Name
- Password
- PasswordCreationDate
- PasswordExpiryDate
- PasswordActive

One simple question. How do my users connect to the database . Offcourse i would need a connection string from the application. That connection string would require a user name and a password isn't it? and I can not get the information from the user table until and unless i am connected to the database.

Another problem, how do i keep track of last 5 password. The policy says that the user can not use any of the last 5 already used passwords.

All this can be avoid if I can get a solution of notifying my users that their Password is due to expire in 'n' days and they must change it before it expires.

What do the other developers do when authenticating their users. Please Guide Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep your user's login credentials in the database, then for access to sql server itself you may only need one login for the entire app. This login would have full access to your database, because it would be up to your application to enforce access rights.

If you go this route, you need to be aware of two things:

1. There is still a security concern for larger applications that need to give ad hoc reporting capabilities to users through tools such as Reporting Services, Crystal Reports, Infomaker, etc. In this case, users can use these reporting tools to gain read access to areas of the database they should not be able to see.
2. If you store your own credential information for your users, you need to make sure you do it properly. That means no plain text passwords. You need a cryptographically secure password hash (not md5!) and a per-user salt. If that's greek to you, best to leave this alone.

Another option open to you is to use Active Directory/Windows Authentication for your database. The trick here is that you still have to set up access rights for all your users. However, you can use Active Directory groups for this to reduce the number of logins you need to create, and it will at least prevent you from needing to reset Sql Server logins by hand, because users will log in with their Active Directory account.

Comment: so using AD, does it mean that once the user is logged into windows, he can just open the application by double click and no user id or password would be asked from him?

Comment: That's right. Sql Server will already know who the user is because of the Active Directory authentication token.

Comment: thats a good idea @joel. and i think is easily implementable. but actually the auditors would require the user to enter user id and password and that too must have password policy enforced.

Comment: Active Directory can enforce password policies, and if this is a web app it will prompt for non-domain-joined computers, just as the auditors want. For domain-joined computers, the auditors are flat out wrong on this, and you need to push back. Doing it this way will be _more_ secure than what they are asking for.

Comment: ok, I understand now. So basically, i don't need to have a user table. all i need is incorporate the Active directory and use those user accounts to authenticate my users. In that case, my connection string would be "integrated security = true"..... correct?

Comment: Something like that, though you often still want to enforce certain things within the application.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty common scenario amongst web applications is to use one username/password (so only one sql login, typically some kind of dedicated login with minimal rights for the application). This way, connection pooling can be used. This is of course a backend account, configured in the web.config and not visible to the end-users.

The users are maintained as a type of data within the application. Asp.net comes with a solution that is called Membership. User authentication is done against the Membership provider and several classes  give you programmataic support for authentication, roles, etc. You can use AD as a provider for example, or forms authentication. Or you can write your own.

Since you are now using a dedicated sql login for each user, you need to be aware that this approach moves data access security to the application level. So this might not always suit your needs.

Comment: thanks... I could have used AD but again the auditors say that one MUST enter login details when the application or webpage is opened. plus ASP.NET memberships can not integrate with the password Policy defined in this same server where SQL server is installed. Or if asp.net gives us that facility then i don't know how to do it

Comment: Well, the whole point is that membership moves the users out of sql server completely so you do not use the Sql server policy anymore except for the service account the application is using... In your case you could use forms authentication, the user always has to enter a username/password in that case

Comment: but thats not how the auditors want. They want to have a login page and all these users must have password policy enforced.

Comment: You enforce the policy in your Membership provider.

Comment: Then the auditors are dumb. Any time you must re-enter credentials is an opportunity for them to be sniffed. Any time you must re-implement an authentication system is an opportunity to get it subtly wrong. The AD approach is more secure because it relies on a proven system, rather than making security novices re-implement authentication for every app.

Comment: I cant see that. Membership provider has only one option AspNetSqlMembershipProvider - TEST  .... nothing else is there to change it to enforce the policy. Am i missing something here

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd use existing Active Directory infrastructure to handle your authentication/authorisation of individual users, and you could then have end-users' credentials passed via the web server to your SQL server (You'd probably need to look into handling the Kerberos "double-hop issue" to effect this).

But failing this, it's easy to set up so that the *application* it self has a SQL login to access the database in order to retrieve *user* level authentication information.  One-way hashes on user passwords would ensure that even if the app's password is read from connection string, user passwords can't be obtained.

Or somewhere in between those two solutions, where the *application* has a *service account* within AD, which has access to the SQL database, in order to retrieve the *user* account info from within the DB.

Either way, if AD is available you can secure further with Kerberos [Service Point Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to ensure database access from only your expected end-point (ie the ASP.NET server).